# What is the name of this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

By [plantri](http://combos.org/plantri), we know that the following graph is the unique planar graph with 15 vertices of minimum degree 5.  I add the graph in *The House of Graphs* ([Graph 49406](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/49406)).
[image]

But I do not know if it has a name.

We note that the unique planar graph with $12$ vertices with minimum degree $5$ is the icosahedral graph and there is no planar graph  with $13$ vertices with minimum degree $5$.

Comment: [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny3lv.png) a nice 3D embedding of this graph. Starting with a triangular prism, we subdivide each triangular face (red and blue vertices) into $4$, which makes the sides hexagonal, and then we put a vertex of degree $6$ (purple) in the middle of each of those hexagonal faces.

Comment: @MishaLavrov A very nice explanation of this graph!